# API Gateway HTTP integration, how do I pass the authorization header?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm in "Integration Request". I've set HTTP integration type and the Endpoint URL.
Below, I see "HTTP Headers, but if I try to add an header, there is a strange "mapped from" value I don't understand.
Setting an HTTP Proxy integration add a Mapping template I also don't understand.

I just need to pass the Authorization:xxxx and X-Auth-Username:xxxxx from the original request to the endpoint

Can't find an easy way...

I set HTTP proxy integration and added in the HTTP Headers (and deployed):

```
 method.request.header.Authorization
 method.request.header.X-Auth-Username
```

I also added as required Authoriaxtion and X-Auth-Username in Method request header as required.
But I get an error upon calling the api:

```
Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. 
Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. 
Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. 
Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header
```

Hmmm maybe it's a "naming" problem?
So I changed "authorization" with MyAuthentication in the  method request, and after in the integration Header, I mapped Authorization to

```
 method.request.header.MyAuthentication
```

Now if I call my api with MyAuthorization in the header, I get "Missing Authentication Token", without hitting the api server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Click on 'Method Request' , expand 'HTTP Request Headers' and add a header `Authorization` . Now go back and click on 'Integration Request' , expand 'HTTP Headers' and add Header Name `Authorization` and 'Mapped from' `method.request.header.Authorization` . Basically for any header XYZ on 'Method Request' tab should have corresponding mapping on 'Integration Request' method.request.header.XYZ .

Answer (score 2):

To Correctly use aws API Gateway as a pure http proxy and make it pass the Authorization header as-is to your backend API, you need to do two things:

1. In the Method Request: Make sure to add the `Authorization` header to the Http Request Headers section.

With this, AWS does not assume that the `Authorization` header is of your own implementation and the gateway does not expect it to contain AWS own format of multiple parameters such as `SignedHeaders`, `Signature`, `X-Amz-Date` , etc..
[image]
2. In the Integration Request: Make sure to select the Use HTTP Proxy Integration.

This makes sure that the request is being sent to the target as-is and thus the `Authorization` header not to be consumed and discarded as part of AWS own SigV4 authorization.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following was correct...I was calling the original api path instead of te api gateway path....

I set HTTP proxy integration and added in the HTTP Headers (and deployed):
    method.request.header.Authorization
    method.request.header.X-Auth-Username