# Aws api gateway add header to forwarded request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently looking into AWS api Gatway and was wondering if it is possible to add a header to a request from a resource where the request is forwarded to another url?

A bit more detail might explain my use case a bit better.

I have an external webservice that requires an apikey to be set in the header. To keep everything a bit more clean and simple, I would like to be able to call my own api gateway and have the api gateway set the header, so that my api gw endpoint can be called without the header (A custom authorizer will be added, so the endpoint is not "public").

I have looked at the documentation and did some experiments in the AWS console, but all I could find, was mapping from an existing data in the request (header, request param etc), but nothing about how to *add* a header.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379176/api-gateway-http-integration-how-do-i-pass-the-authorization-header#:~:text=Click%20on%20%27Method%20Request%27%2C%20expand%20%27HTTP%20Request%20Headers%27,add%20Header%20Name%20Authorization%20and%20%27Mapped%20from%27%20method.request.header.Authorization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [API Gateway HTTP integration, how do I pass the authorization header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379176/api-gateway-http-integration-how-do-i-pass-the-authorization-header)